# Can I add border for starts in rate component from ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I use Rate component from antd, but I want do two things:

1. Prevent scale of start when hover on it if it is disabled (read-only)
2. Add border to empty stars (if value = 3, 4th and 5th start need gray border)
   How can I achieve it?

Comment: Not start, but star in the first option.

Comment: I know about character prop, but can I pass one my own component like unpicked element and another like picked for customizing this component?